# Regex for finding special entries in a multiline setting

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for certain entries with special words in a string. The string looks like this.

```
entry 1: hello
entry 2: world
entry 3: this
is a multiline
that makes it hard
entry 4: here we have a special entry
entry 5: here
we
have 
another special entry
in a multiline
entry 6: end
```

Because it is an multiline problem I use Java's DOTALL so that the `.` matches also newline characters.

I am looking for entries that have the word *special* in it.

First I tried to find a regex, that captures a full entry: `entry \d+: .*?(?=\s*(entry \d: )|\Z)`. That is like a simplified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864020/parse-multiline-log-entries-using-a-regex)

Then I thought, ok I just have to exchange the `.*?` for the regex I need to find. But `entry \d+: .*?special.*?(?=\s*(entry \d: )|\Z)` does not work, probably because the *special* breaks the greed of the expression.

Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```java
(?s)entry \d+: (?:(?!entry \d+: ).)*special.*?(?=\s*entry \d+: |$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLx5Hl/2/). *Details*:

- `entry \d+:`  - `entry` + space + one or more digits, `:`, space
- `(?:(?!entry \d+: ).)*` - any char, repeated zero or more times, that does not start the *`entry` + space + one or more digits, `:`, space* sequence
- `special` - a fixed string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*entry \d+: |$)` -  a positive lookahead that matches a location in string that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces, `entry`, space, one or more digits, `:` and space, or end of the string.

**NOTE**: Do not use `Pattern.MULTILINE` with this regex. Or, keep on using `\Z` (end of the string, or position right before the trailing newline, LF char).

Answer (score 0):

[Edit:] I unfortunately missed the multiline nature of entries, so this answer is valid for single line entries but will return only the first line for multiline entries. I think one *could* overcome this by setting a certain regex for delimiter, though.

I'd suggest you use a `Scanner` to deal with the multi line aspect. This will give you a stream of tokens (the lines). You can use a `String.contains(...)` or a `String.matches(...)` to filter tokens then.

```
var result = new Scanner(myMultiLineString).tokens()
                                           .useDelimiter("\\n")
                                           // alternatively use String.contains(...)
                                           // if you're looking for a constant
                                           // rather than a complex rule.
                                           .filter(s -> s.matches(regex))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This way you will only find lines with required words, not the whole entries as they could be multiline

Comment: Thanks for the hint, indeed I missed that. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you use words and space classes instead of dots then it seems to work

```
/entry \d+: [\w\s]*special[\w\s]*?(?=\s*(?:entry \d+:)|$)/gm
```

It seems that if you allow the colon `:` in your text, it breaks the expression.

And also you have `\Z` in your expression but it seems to me that end of line `$` is more suited here

Comment: Also the lookahead should match a multi digit entry numbers as well, so please edit `\d` to `\d+` inside the lookahead.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know _why_ the colon breaks the expression?

Comment: I think there is one catch with this solution. The regex only matches an entry up to the line in which the _special_ is included. In the example the match of entry 5 does not match the line before the last ("in a multiline").

Comment: I think it finds the first entry and as `entry 123:` now matches `[\w\s:]*` proceeds through all the entries till it finds one with `special` in it

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Unfortunately, this solution does not solve my problem, because there are colons (as well as other punctuation marks) allowed in the text of the entry.

Comment: Maybe then it's a good idea to first separate your entries in the list of strings and then search for the special words in these strings